# Data Manipulation with R

Tags: r, transactions, dataframe

i have a problem where i found myself no good solution in time. Really appreciate any assistance as i think its for some professionals in here just a few lines of code.

my data contains over 2 mio. rows of transactions. I want to do some sort of association rules on the data.

I´m just interested in transactions (t_ID) which have the Product(P_ID) "PANDORA" involved and where i know the customer (c_ID). I Made an example:

```
> T_ID <- c(10,10,10,11,12,13,13)
> P_ID <- c("PANDORA", "Others", "Pan","PANDORA","Ham", "PANDORA","Ham")
> c_ID <- c(1,1,1,2,-1,4,4)
> basket <- data.frame(T_ID,P_ID,c_ID)
> basket
T_ID    P_ID c_ID
1   10 PANDORA    1
2   10  Others    1
3   10     Pan    1
4   11 PANDORA    2
5   12     Ham   -1
6   13 PANDORA    4
7   13     Ham    4
```

Transaction 10 contains the product "Pandora", therefore all 3 Rows should remain in the dataset. While Transaction 12 has no Customer attached it needs to be removed.

Im struggling the most on the part how to keep the transaction rows which are related to the same transaction ID containing "PANDORA" but have another product stored.

Any help greatly appreciated,

Best regards, 
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does each transaction have only one customer id?  I'm assuming so.

First step is to remove those rows which do not have customer id.

```
cleanbasket = basket[bucket$c_ID != -1,]
```

Next, we want to identify which transactions include PANDORA.

```
transactions = unique(basket$T_ID[basket$P_ID == "PANDORA"])
```

Then get all the rows for these transactions

```
cleanbasket = cleanbasket[cleanbasket$T_ID %in% transactions,]
```

Comment: Worked out just fine. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
keep_IDs <- basket$T_ID[with(basket, P_ID=="PANDORA" & c_ID!=-1)]
basket[basket$T_ID %in% keep_IDs,]
#  T_ID    P_ID c_ID
#1   10 PANDORA    1
#2   10  Others    1
#3   10     Pan    1
#4   11 PANDORA    2
#6   13 PANDORA    4
#7   13     Ham    4
```

**data**

```
basket <- structure(list(T_ID = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L), 
P_ID = structure(c(6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Ham","Honey", "Nugget", "Others", "Pan", "PANDORA"), class = "factor"), 
c_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, -1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), 
.Names = c("T_ID", "P_ID", "c_ID"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I did extend my example and added another transaction (14) with "Nugget" and "Honey" in it and bought by Customer 5. Its also showing still now transaction 14. So it seems to work for the example but not overall.

Comment: @Christian I think you're mistaken. I added the transaction you mentioned, and it does not show up in the output. Please double-check with the data I posted in the edit.

Comment: You might have forgotten to store the output in a variable, like `basket2 <- basket[basket$T_ID %in% keep_IDs,]`. The original data frame `basket` remains unchanged by the operations in my answer. They only filter the content to yield the desired output.

Comment: You´re right. I double checked and it works out just fine now. Thanks a lot!